# How to validate that a number is not toll free?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to validate that a number is not toll free but not sure how to set this up via the baked in validation helpers.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
validates :local_phone, :format => { :with => /^(\+?1)?(8(00|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$/, :message => "cannot be a toll-free number" }
```

However, it validates that the number is toll free.  I've tried to switch it via ! but to no avail.  Before writing my own validates_with class I thought it may be best to ask around.

Comment: Did you add the `!` in the regex or was that originally there?  I don't think `?!` means anything special (unless they are the first characters after an opening paren) so currently you would only match numbers that had a literal `!` in them.

Comment: Oop sorry - the ! wasn't originally there - I had added it.

Comment: Going to answer my own question - this works:

validates :local_phone, :format => { :with => /^(?!(+?1)?(8(00|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})).{10}$/, :message => "cannot be a toll-free number" }

Comment: @Northband Add an actual answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

How to validate that a number is not toll free? 
Just call that number and find out :-)

He got the answer already (refer the above comment). I'm just *reposting* it again so that this question won't appear in "*Unanswered*" section.

```
validates :local_phone, :format => { 
   :with => /^(?!(+?1)?(8(00|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})).{10}$/, 
   :message => "cannot be a toll-free number" }
```

Comment: I get an "Invalid regular expression" error when I use this as is.

Comment: Try this one: ``/^(\+?1)?(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})/``.